# How should I handle Python list properties with respect to getters/setters?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, properties

It is my understanding that one aspect of the Pythonic way is to use direct member variable access of classes until 'getters/setters' are needed.  Code is available on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/bWfxuf)

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, friends=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        if friends is None:
            self.friends = []
        else:
            self.friends = friends

me = Person('Mr. Me')
you = Person('Ms. You')

me.age = 42
me.friends.append(you)
```

Because of the @property decorator approach this access to member variable `age` can be 'converted' to a 'getter/setter' interface in the future without rewriting the line that sets it to 42.  But what about the last line where I add `you` to my `friends` list?  **Is it possible for the `Person` class to intercept the `append()` call and take other actions?**  Perhaps in the future I would decide to add the feature that `you` would get notified that they have been added to `me`'s `friends` list.

Comment: You can't "intercept" `me.friends.append(you)` while `Person.friends` is a vanilla `list`, but you could provide a method: `def append_friend(self, friend):`

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I think that your 'vanilla list' reference probably triggered me to realize I needed to create an additional class, so thanks for seeding my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, once I ask the question my brain turns on and comes up with a solution.  Let me know if this is good or not.  Instead of intercepting the `.append()` call in `Person`, create a class `PersonFriendList(List)` and override `append()` with the desired functionality.  Then, instead of assigning `[]` to `self.friends` assign `PersonFriendList()`.  The `.friend` value should probably also get decorated as a `@property` so that assignment can be intercepted by `Person` to avoid `.friend` being written to the wrong kind of list.

Code available on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/UELlOC).

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, friends=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        if friends is None:
            friends = []
        self.friends = PersonFriendList(friends)


class PersonFriendList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(PersonFriendList, self).__init__(*args)
        self.DebugPrint('constructed with {}'.format(str(*args)))

    def DebugPrint(self, string):
        print('{}(): {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, string))

    def append(self, *args):
        super(PersonFriendList, self).append(*args)
        self.DebugPrint('appending {}'.format(str(*args)))

me = Person('Mr. Me')
you = Person('Ms. You')

me.age = 42
me.friends.append(you)
```